# Dynamic XAML and events handling

Tags: c#, wpf, events, xaml

I have a WPF Window that was created dynamically by loading a XAML script, which is part of a bigger script(Proprietary) that we support.

This Script contains supports for user actions like  text box lost focus / Check box checked  / Button clicked etc..

Say I have a pre written C# class meant to support functionalities of the class.

Since the windows is dynamic it might contain any number of basic UI element like button, radio button check box edit box etc.

How do I link XAML to every possible action on the dialog box, like text box lost focus / Check box checked  / Button clicked etc.

Ideally if I can get Name of the UI Element Action and a string from XAML into C# class that is perfect.

example Button1, "Clicked" "Button1_Clicked" here Button1_Clicked is a string that has been passed from XAML which helps me call the function “Button1_Clicked” in my scripting

language. Similarly for a text Box it could be Text1, "LostFocus" "Text1_LostFocus" etc..

How can I write my supporting class and the XAML script to achieve the above mentioned scenario..

Answer (score 0):

just have a look at this post

[Loading XAML XML through runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077318/loading-xaml-xml-through-runtime/4077786#4077786)