# WPF: Load XAML file, which contains the x:Code element

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I need load, and use XAML file.

I have wrote simple XAML file:

```
<Window      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="300" Title="My Window">
    <x:Code>
        <![CDATA[
            void btnMyButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello world", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
        ]]>
    </x:Code>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnMyButton" x:FieldModifier="public" Margin="10" Padding="10" 
                FontSize="20" Click="btnMyButton_Click_1">My button</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then I try to load this XAML in my code:

```
String curDir = io.Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Lisp_Wpf.Commands).Assembly.Location);
String xamlFileName = "MyWindow.xaml";
String fileFullName = io.Path.Combine(curDir, xamlFileName);
DependencyObject depObj = default(DependencyObject);
using (io.FileStream fs = new io.FileStream(fileFullName, io.FileMode.Open)) {
    depObj = XamlReader.Load(fs) as DependencyObject;
    fs.Close();
}
if (depObj != null && depObj is Window) {
    Window win = (Window)depObj;
    acad.ShowModalWindow(win);
}
```

But I get exception:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred: 'Failed to create a
>   'Failed to create a 'Click' from the text 'btnMyButton_Click_1'.' Line 
>   number '16' and line position '31'.

I found such info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750494.aspx):

> Code declared within x:Code for WPF has several notable limitations:
>     ...
>     x:Class Directive must be provided on the parent root element.
>     ...

But if I add in my `Window` element the `x:Class` attribute:

```
x:Class="Lisp_Wpf.MainWindow"
```

then I get exception:

> 'Specified class name 'Lisp_Wpf.MainWindow' doesn't match actual root instance type 
>   'System.Windows.Window'. Remove the Class directive or provide an instance via 
>   XamlObjectWriterSettings.RootObjectInstance.' Line number '1' and line position '14'.

In my MS Visual Studio project the XML file has properties:
Build Action = None;
Copy To Output Directory = copy always;
Custom Tools = (empty string);

The partial CS file for this XAML I deleted.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to load xaml at runtime you cannot give any code behind your XAML file.Probably you can just attach general event for the Button click and identity the controls at runtime - Just have look at the below link and try it out.

[Loading XAML XML through runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077318/loading-xaml-xml-through-runtime/4077786#4077786)

Comment: Thank you for link.
From documentation:
> The code placed within x:Code will be treated by 
> compilation to be within the scope of the partial 
> class that is already being created for that XAML 
> page. Therefore all code you define must be members 
> or variables of that partial class.
I won't be able to use x:Code without the partial class. :(((

Comment: I wanted to write function for AutoLISP to AutoCAD in order that from LISP it was possible to open the WPF windows. If connection of an event handler can't be made without the partial class or without code.NET, it won't help me.

Answer (score 2):

General hint (I did not reproduce your specific problem):

In WPF this error comes also if the **Build Action** in Visual Studio to was set to "Resource" (you find the setting under properties of the xaml file). **Set the Build Action to "Page" and it will compile!**