# Get XAML code in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I get XAML code of a window as a string, change this string, and upload this string as a xaml-code of window?

For example, I have

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Margin="0,0,9,38" Name="button1" Height="82" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="132"></ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and I want to have this xaml code in the end

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Margin="0,0,9,38" Name="button1" Height="82" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="132">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <local:d_dddw_imp_insurance_list />
             </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Pretty sure window's XAML is not available because it gets _compiled_.  If you want to change your _window_, just use WPF APIs.  No need to fiddle with XAML at runtime

Comment: what do yo mean by upload?

Comment: Changing the way things are displayed at run-time is not done by modifying xaml as text. What do you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your using wpf/xaml with c#, visual studio generally compile the xaml code to c#, to be as performant as possible. If you want to have some dynamic XAML, you need to use `XamlReader` to read xaml and display at "on your own".

Just take a look at: [Loading XAML XML through runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4077786/2630261)

Than you can change or manipulate the xaml and display the result very easily.