# WPF - Rendering a Xaml Segment

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a WPF app. In this app, I have some XAML segments. I need to display the XAML segments in a `TextBlock`. In my XAML, I have the following line:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=XamlSegment, Converter={StaticResource XamlToTextConverter}}" />
```

The `XamlSegment` property will have a value like "-0.275*x2". In an attempt to render this XAML in my UI so that the Superscript shows, I'm using the `XamlToTextConverter`, which is defined as follows:

```
namespace MyApp.Converters
{
  public class XamlToTextConverter : IValueConverter
  {
     private static readonly Regex Regex = new Regex("(<.*?)>(.*)(</.*?>)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
       // value looks like this: -0.275*x<Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">2</Run>
       var xamlText = value as string;
       if (xamlText != null)
       {
         try
         {
           xamlText = "<TextBlock>" + xamlText + "</TextBlock>";

           var xamlTextWithNamespace = Regex.Replace(xamlText, "$1 xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">$2$3");
           return XamlReader.Parse(xamlTextWithNamespace);
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
           return value;
         }
       }
       else
       {
         return value;
       }
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
   }
}
```

When this converter gets ran, my UI shows "System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock" instead of the rendered XAML. Yet, I don't know why. How do I get my `XamlSegment` to render in my UI?

Thanks

Comment: According to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc663033(v=vs.110).aspx), `XamlReader.Parse` method should return the `TextBlock` object.

Comment: @Colin `XamlReader.Parse` is returning a `TextBlock` object. However, in the actual UI, its priting "System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock" instead of actually rendering the TextBlock. I don't understand why though or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The Text property of the TextBlock will be set to a `TextBlock` object according to your `XamlToTextConverter`. Since the Text property should be type of `string`, it doesn't know how to show a `TextBlock` as string. So the default way to get thing done is to use the `ToString` method on `TextBlock` to fill the Text property, which makes the value of Text as "System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock".
It seems that you would like to dynamically render the xaml. You could reference this link([Loading XAML XML through runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077318/loading-xaml-xml-through-runtime)) for a solution.