# Is it possible to store and later retrieve user-configured WPF/XAML User Controls in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, xaml

I'm relatively new to `.NET` development (though I have a lot of Java experience) and I'm trying to see if that what I want to do is possible. I want to create a drag-and-drop template builder so that users can add and position things like comboboxes and textboxes on a gridpanel. Later, users can be assigned an instance of this item to complete.

Here's the ideal process:

- Manager creates template using d&d builder to position fields. The number of fields are unknown by me, the programmer (but have a cap, like 15-20) at design time.
- On save, this new control (the grid and all of the controls it's wrapped around) is added to a SQL database
- Later, the manager assigns an instance of this process to an employee.
- The employee opens the item, and queries the DB for the control.
- The control is added to a content area (designated by me at design time).
- Any existing data is populated into the fields of the control.
- At save, the user saves the data for the fields.

For now `SQL` is non-negotiable. I have already worked out how I'm going to store the data for the fields, I just need to know how to store the actual visual element exactly as configured, and how to display said element to users.

Thoughts?

Comment: You should go learn what XAML is and how it's related to WPF.

Comment: The entire question text doesn't explain why you think the *UI code* should be written in the database. XAML is similar to HTML. You don't store HTML in the database, you store data, generate ViewModels from that data and *data-binding* to bind the ViewModels to the Views. MVVM was created for WPF first and later adopted by almost all HTML/JavaScript frameworks

Comment: This is not a good way to think about it. You should think about serializing viewmodel classes to your database.

Comment: As for *designing* forms, it's the same thing as HTML. Data binding and templates means that each object and type can have its own template. A string can be displayed as rotating flaming letters if you want. You get flow controls just like you do with HTML. Vertical or horizontal panels, wrapping panels. The template for a single ListBox item can be a complex element containing pictures and multiple lines of text. That's how the WPF demos you've seen work. You *don't* need to specify the location of each field

Comment: Ran across this article which seems to discuss accessing the XAML for an application through C# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077318/loading-xaml-xml-through-runtime/4077786#4077786. I would think you could do something similar then store the resultant XML down in SQL, or wherever.

Comment: Okay - I think I'm understanding what I need to do here. Basically the user needs to have any custom controls that will be used, but the actual organization of said controls will be handled through XAML, which I can store in SQL and then pull later?